# Setting PRAGMA CIPHER on db with sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js, sqlcipher

i see that sequelize is compatible with sqlite's sqlcipher extension ([docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html) | [merged pr](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/6366)). the code suggests a way to authenticate on the db instance, but i can't find a way to set the cipher.

using sqlite3, can run something like this:

```js
var sqlite = require('sqlite3);
var db = new sqlite.Database('test.db');
db.serialize(
  // some sql commands
);
```

with the sequelize orm for sqlite i can get a db created, but can't get an encrypted instance:

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = new Sequelize('test.db', 'username', 'secretAsPragmaKey', {option1: true, option2: false});
db.query(
  // some sql
);
```

i've tried running queries on this instance to explicitly set `PRAGMA KEY` to the password param, and `PRAGMA CIPHER` to sqlcipher's default [`aes-256-cfb`], but not while using sequelize.

does the encrypted db need to exist, and sequelize is just opening it? if so, how to ensure the keyed db exists without inserting tables?